# How to get all rows where the timestamp hours are between specific hours with Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table and I want to retrieve all rows for a `date` column like `2022-10-24 21:03:00` where the hours for every date are between `21:00:00` and `22:00:00`.

What would the SQL for this?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the hour from the timestamp and use that:

```
select *
from mytable
where extract(hour from timestamp_column) = 21;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hour`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#hour) function:

```sql
select *
from mytable
where hour(date_time) = 21;
```

If you need a particular day then use `date_trunc`:

```sql
select *
from mytable
where date_trunc('hour', date_time) = timestamp '2022-10-24 21:00:00';
```